# Do you need the full .NET 4.0 Framework installed to use Win API?

Tags: c#, winapi, .net-4.0

I am about to release my pet project and let other people to use it. It is WinForm application that heavily relies on Win API.

Will people need to download Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile or will they need to have full .NET4 framework?

Comment: You decide that in your Project|Properties|Application dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile is the framework runtime, that should be all that is needed.  But as it says [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24872) ---> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile redistributable package installs the .NET Framework runtime and associated files that are required to run most client applications.

Then I guess it's a matter of what your using and you would have to test it on a machine that does not have .net 4 already.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what framework version your project targets.

You can check that in the solution properties in Visual Studio but right-clicking on the project and choosing properties.

Comment: It says .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, it's just I have an issue, people been complaining that the program doesn't open for them.

Comment: @Dmitris - if you have any 3rd party dependencies you'll need to make sure they are also included with your app.  Can you include the error message your users get in your question?

Comment: I am not sure how to get this message, he said the program just crashes and that's it. Is there are way to get the message logged somewhere?

Comment: You could add a `try..catch` block which then outputs the exception data to a log file for your user to send to you.

Comment: Good suggestion, I went with example from MSDN I think that what I need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx#Y0 it handles both Thread exceptions and Unhandled exceptions